# jquery ajax return problem with attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am responding an ajax request with a js file.

```
$('#liststudents').html("<button>Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
```

and the problem occurs if i try to use ANY HTML PROPERTY like,

```
$('#liststudents').html("<button class="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
$('#liststudents').html("<button href="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
```

any of these fails, but i cannot see why?

Comment: actually every answer is true, but i am going to select the one with escaping, because it is the way i think which will fit every situation about this problem, thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a quote appear in your output you need to escape them with a \ character, like

```
$('#liststudents').html("<button class=\"\">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because of the `"` inside your string.
Try this:

```
$('#liststudents').html("<button class=''>Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
$('#liststudents').html("<button href=''>Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>");
```

With

```
"<button class="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>"
```

the String is this:

```
"<button class="
```

because the last `"` "terminates" the string. And this will produce an error.

Comment: Tim's right. Change `""` to `''` .i.e. the double-quotes inside the string to single-quotes. Though why do you want an empty CLASS or HREF?

Comment: I think it is only an example. Of course it oes not make sense to have an empty `class` or `href`.

Comment: i am actually writing some stuff in that blank quotes :D but i tried to make the code simplified

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing those double quotes. And those two statements seem to be redundant as the second overwrites the work of the first. Try this instead:

```
$('#liststudents').html('<button href="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>');
```

or even better:

```
$('#liststudents')
    .empty()
    .append($('<button/>').attr('href', '').text('Duzenle'))
    .text('24 Name Surname')
    .append('<br/>');
```

And by the way a [`<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) tag doesn't have an `href` attribute so you might need to adapt this if you want valid markup.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `"` as a JS delimiter, thus your content can't contain `"`.

```
$('#liststudents').html('<button class="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>');
$('#liststudents').html('<button href="">Duzenle</button> 24 Name Surname<br/>');
```

If the answer comes from Rails, use the [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper.

```
$('#liststudents').html('<%= escape_javascript(@variable) %>');
```